# How do I tie together 2 asynchronous request.post calls in Express and NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm still learning how to make calls with using Express. Single asynchronous calls are no problem, but now I have an example where I want to feed the result of one call into the next one.
My current code can be seen below, a really messy way that includes a forloop like function, a foreach and a Timeout. I'd like to learn the proper way to do this. Preferably something that scales.

The first call fills up a result object `getWorkbooksResponse` with a list of workbooks (incl. workbook id's and workbook names). The second part fires of a `getViews` call for each workbook in that list. The function `checkResponse` sorts through the views and puts them in alphabetical order by name.

**What is the proper way to tie together 2 request.post calls?**
I've been looking at next(), bluebird, async,... but some examples would definitely help.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router = express.Router();

//initialize values
var workbookId = -1;

router.get('/workbooks/views', function(req, res) {
  var workgroup = req.query.workgroup;
  var authToken = req.query.auth_token;
  var serverUrl = req.query.server_url;

  //Assemble body for POST request...
  var requestedBody = {
    method: 'getWorkbooks',
    params: {
      page: {
        startIndex: 0,
        maxItems: 999
      },
      filter: {
        operator: 'and',
        clauses: []
      }
    }
  };

  //Send POST request...
  request.post({
    url: 'https://' + serverUrl + '/vizportal/api/web/v1/getWorkbooks',
    body: JSON.stringify(requestedBody),
    headers: {
      'Cookie': 'workgroup_session_id=' + workgroup + '; XSRF-TOKEN=' + authToken,
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': authToken
    }
  }, function(err, response, body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    var result = body.result;

    if (result.errors) {
      return res.json({
        http_code: 401
      });
    } else {
      getWorkbooksResponse = result;
      var getViewsWorkbooksResponse = [];

      var forloop = function(i) {
        if (i < getWorkbooksResponse.totalCount) {
          workbookId = getWorkbooksResponse.workbooks[i].id;
          var workbookName = getWorkbooksResponse.workbooks[i].name;

          request.post({
            url: 'https://' + serverUrl + '/vizportal/api/web/v1/getViews',
            body: JSON.stringify({
              method: 'getViews',
              params: {
                page: {
                  startIndex: 0,
                  maxItems: 999
                },
                filter: {
                  operator: 'and',
                  clauses: [{
                    operator: 'eq',
                    field: 'workbookId',
                    value: workbookId
                  }]
                }
              }
            }),
            headers: {
              'Cookie': 'workgroup_session_id=' + workgroup + '; XSRF-TOKEN=' + authToken,
              'X-XSRF-TOKEN': authToken
            }

          }, function(err, response, body) {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            var result = body.result;

            if (result.errors) {
              response = {
                http_code: 401
              };
            } else {
              result.views.forEach(function(view) {
                view.workbookName = workbookName;
                getViewsWorkbooksResponse.push(view);
              });
            }
          });

          forloop(i + 1);
        } else {

          var checkResponse = function() {
            if (getViewsWorkbooksResponse) {

              //Alphabetize Response array on view name
              getViewsWorkbooksResponse.sort(function(a, b){
                return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
              });

              return res.json({
                http_code: 200,
                response: getViewsWorkbooksResponse
              });
            }
          };
          setTimeout(checkResponse, 1000);
        }
      };

      if (getWorkbooksResponse.totalCount) {
        forloop(0);
      }
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are you using promises? because if you use promises then this is really easy to achieve, you could also look at the async library for js, it has stuff like async.series

Comment: I'm using promises on front-end, but back-end is what you see here. I take it from your comment I need an additional external library (either using callbacks or promises) then?

Comment: I would look at async. I would also look into promises, they will make a world of difference

Answer (score 0):

With promises it would be the simplest way:

You wrap your request.post calls in

```
new Promise((resolve,reject)=>
{ ... 
  request.post(...,function(err,response, body){
          if (result.errors){reject(/* error info here */)}
          else {resolve(/* data goes here */)}
          }
});
```

And then use

`Promise.all[promise1,...,promiseN].then(function(result){
    //here is where you gonna do things after all requests are done
})`